# Unable to search LDAP server using PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to search Active Directory if the user exists. I am getting the following error message.
 'Unable to search LDAP server'. 
What could be wrong? Please suggest.

```
<?php

// LDAP variables
$ldaphost = "servername";  // your ldap servers
$ldapport = 389;                 // your ldap server's port number

// Connecting to LDAP
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldaphost, $ldapport)
          or die("Could not connect to $ldaphost");


$user = 'mylastname';

//search user in /Admin/IT/Users

$dn = "OU=Admin, OU=IT, OU=Users,   DC=school, DC=edu";

$filter = "(sAMAccountName=" . $user . ")";
$attr = array("memberof");
$result = ldap_search($ldapconn , $dn, $filter, $attr) or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");
$entries = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);
echo $entries["count"]." entries returned\n";

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking to Active Directory server, you should always set ldap protocol version to 3 and turn off referral handling:

```
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
```

Also, a Distinguished Name should not have its parts space-delimited - reformat it as follows:

```
$dn = "OU=Admin,OU=IT,OU=Users,DC=school,DC=edu";
```

And lastly, if something goes wrong, always check [what the LDAP server says](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-error.php)!

```
$result = ldap_search($ldapconn, $dn, $filter, $attr) or exit("Unable to search LDAP server, response was: " . ldap_error($ldapconn));
```

Comment: I added ldap_set_option but I am still getting Warning: ldap_get_entries() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean

Comment: Maybe `ldap_search` does not return a `false`-like value and that's why you never get to the `die` statement - try to `echo` whatever is returned by `ldap_error` immediately after your `ldap_search` statement and check what you get...

Comment: I am getting the following error message. bool(false) string(16) "Operations error" int(1)

Comment: Have you updated the BaseDN to NOT include spaces after commas? Are you setting the ldap options after you have created the connection but before you do the search? Are you authenticated using [ldap_bind](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php)? And, are you sure that the Base DN is correct? Does it really exist in AD?

Comment: Base DN exist in AD. I am using ldap_bind now. Now it displays the blank page. I am not sure how to trouble shoot.

Comment: Try to search for all objects in that base DN and see if you are getting at least something - modify your search filter to *(objectClass=\*)*.