# PHP - LDAP with SSL fail to bind

Tags: php, ssl, active-directory, ldap

I have PHP 7.0 on CentOS 7. And I've installed `php-ldap` module as well.

```
# yum install -y php php-ldap
...
# php -m
...
ldap
...
```

Now the following PHP codes works:

```
<?php
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("dc.example.com", 389) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
    
if ($ldapconn) {
    $ldaprdn  = 'username';
    $ldappass = 'password';

    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);
    
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
    }
}

$Result = ldap_search($ldapconn, "DC=example,DC=com", "(sAMAccountName=johndoe)");
$data = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $Result);

print_r($data);
?>
```

That works! I can connect, bind, and then even search for username `johndoe` and view his entire AD profile successfully.

### Problem

But then I tried with SSL via port `636`:

```
<?php
putenv('LDAPTLS_REQCERT=require');
putenv('LDAPTLS_CACERT=/var/www/html/servercert.der'); #I know, but this is just temporary location
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("dc.example.com", 636) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

if ($ldapconn) {
    $ldaprdn  = 'username';
    $ldappass = 'password';

    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);
    
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
    }
}

$Result = ldap_search($ldapconn, "DC=example,DC=com", "(sAMAccountName=johndoe)");
$data = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $Result);

print_r($data);
?>
```

I got this error:

```
Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in /var/www/html/index.php on line 14
LDAP bind failed...
Warning: ldap_search(): Search: Can't contact LDAP server in......
```

What am I missing please?

Note:

1. We have port 636 opened on Windows AD Server and it is reachable from this PHP web server.
2. Server certificate is valid.

Comment: "What am I missing please?" The problem is probably not in your code. Are you sure your LDAP server is indeed running and listening on port 636? Are you sure there is no firewall blocking that traffic. You should try with command line client from same host to double check the LDAP connection then only go back to PHP.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek hi, I'm sorry, "LDAP server"? I think I'm using php-ldap module already. Which is not the one?

Comment: See error message. Your code is an LDAP client, that connects (through the library) to an LDAP server. The error message tells you that your code can not connect to that server. See `ldap_connect` instruction that specify which server to connect to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the `ldap_connect` should be as below:

```
ldap_connect("ldaps://dc.example.com:636")
```

And then all of sudden it worked!

*Note: If it is on Apache, it is worth restarting it after changing to above code.*